# StateObject property doesn't update view but ObservedObject does

Tags: ios, swiftui, realm

I am saving data to Realm DB in another View where I use  `@EnvironmentObject var modelData : DBViewModel`
and loading them in this View

```
struct SelectedSinsList: View {
@StateObject var modelData = DBViewModel() //@ObservedObject works, as it always recreates the List when I open this view and values are updated
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView{
            VStack(spacing: 15){
                ForEach(modelData.sins){sin in //..........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior indicates that the only reason your view is updating with new data is that a parent view is redrawing, thus triggering the "unowned" observed object to be rebuilt.

State and StateObject outlast the View struct’s body being invalidated and redrawn. To use those, you’ll need to connect the callback or publisher in the StateObject to its objectWillChange publisher by calling self.objectWillChange.send()

But if that DBViewModel is already an environmentObject, why recreate it?

Comment: Thanks, I found out my understanding of EnvironmentObject was a bit wrong, ..now I am creating an instance of DBViewModel in top View while also setting .environmentObject(modelData) to all subviews so they have ancestor, and then using @EnvironmentObject modelData everywhere else (in those views).

Comment: Yep. State/StateObject = owned in that view's lifecycle (that's what you'd use in that top level View or App struct). You may also find environmentObject a great way to pass down colors and dimension information, rather than using global constants. Even a ButtonStyle or ViewModifier will receive the environment. One thing though... using the same view model for a huge section of your app is inadvisable as it becomes brittle and all-knowing. You may still want to create individual ViewModels, but use an environmentObject factory to instantiate those ViewModels and pass them their data.

Comment: If you go for the factory approach, you can look in my answer history for how to get the view models to fire their objectWillChange publisher.